# Docker-compose works, just Docker using Dockerfile - does not. Why?

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn, google-cloud-run

I'm not a Docker expert by any means so maybe it has a simple solution. I have such "strange" problem:
for a long time in local development I used Docker-compose for my Python Flask gunicorn server with a pretty simple setup, my `docker-compose.yaml` looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services: 
    website:
        build: .
        command: >
            gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:443
            --reload
            --workers=2
            --timeout 0
            --certfile=scert.crt
            --keyfile=skey.key
            db_app.app:create_app()
        environment: 
            PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 'true'
        volumes: 
            - '.:/db_app'
        ports: 
            - '443:443'
```

I usually started it with `docker-compose up --build`, refreshing local files automatically rebuilt the server and so on - great. Client app connected without any problems too. But now I need to have it working with just Dockerfile (putting it out there on Google Cloud Run). I came up with this one:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

ENV INSTALL_PATH /db_app
RUN mkdir -p ${INSTALL_PATH}

WORKDIR ${INSTALL_PATH}

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 443
CMD exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:443 --reload --workers=2 --threads 8 --timeout 0 --certfile=scert.crt --keyfile=skey.key db_app.app:create_app
```

It builds okay, runs okay but.. whenever I try to connect with my client app, I get 503. It happens both on the Google Cloud Run and locally where I just don't see any output from the server, even though it does run (when starting it with `docker run containername` so it executes the dockerfile and not with docker-compose (which works just fine)). What did I do wrong?

Additional information:

Result of `docker run containername ls -l /db_app`

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 17 16:12 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  496 Nov 14 11:13 docker-compose.yaml
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 16 20:34 instance
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  252 Oct 11 15:37 requirements.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1456 Oct 15 14:09 scert.crt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1704 Oct 15 14:09 skey.key
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 27 18:05 db_app
```

Comment: Could you post the result of `docker run containername ls -l /db_app` ?

Comment: @emi Posted it.

Comment: Is that correct? I see there is a `/db_app/db_app` directory.

Comment: Do your app needs any database instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question, cause I figured out what was wrong.

Apparently, Google Cloud Run takes care of the security by itself, it doesn't want us to use any self-signed or otherwise generated certificates with the container instance output. To be safe I also used the default port.
Removing the lines about that from Gunicorn command made it work and properly respond to client (which still connects with https).

So this is the only change that was needed to the Dockerfile:

```
CMD exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --reload --workers=1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 "db_app.app:create_app()"
```

Bottom line here is that Google uses own certificates for this and doesn't need ours.